How to Implement photo-sphere-viewer for 360 view in Angular 10?
I'm working on an Angular 10 project and would like to integrate the photo-sphere-viewer library to display 360-degree images. However, I'm having difficulty setting it up correctly within Angular 10. I have already installed photo-sphere-viewer using npm, but I'm unsure how to properly import and use it within my Angular components.
Could anyone provide a step-by-step guide or an example of how to implement photo-sphere-viewer in Angular 10?
Any advice on best practices for Angular compatibility would also be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/

First we can install the library photo-sphere-viewer, using the below command:
npm install @photo-sphere-viewer/core

Then we need to install it's dependency three.js, using the below command:
npm i three.js
npm i --save-dev @types/three

Make sure you have the meta definition for proper resolution as mentioned in their getting started guide.
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  </body>
</html>

You have to include the relevant CSS for the photo viewer. I am adding it to the global styles css file.
styles.css
@import '../node_modules/@photo-sphere-viewer/core/index.css';

html,
body,
#viewer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

You can create a custom directive PhotoSphereViewerDirective which takes an input of the photo viewer configuration and we use it to initialize the photo viewer, on the ngAfterViewInit hook (fires when view/HTML is initialized).
@Directive({
  selector: '[photoSphereViewer]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class PhotoSphereViewerDirective {
  @Input('photoSphereViewer') viewerConfig = {};
  element = inject(ElementRef);

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const viewer = new Viewer({
      container: this.element.nativeElement,
      ...this.viewerConfig,
    });
  }
}

Finally we use this directive in the component by adding it to the imports array.
Here you are using angular 10, so no standalone components, all you need to do is get rid of standalone: true of the directive decorator. Then add it to the declarations array of the app module or other modules you want to use this directive in.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [PhotoSphereViewerDirective],
  styles: [`:host {display: block;height:100vh;width:100vh}`],
  template: `
    <div [photoSphereViewer]="viewerConfig" id="viewer"></div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  viewerConfig = {
    panorama:
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Greenland_scenery.jpg',
  };
}

Stackblitz Demo
Reference - Code Sandbox
